# What is the meaning of build according to Jenkins site

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

According to the official site of Jenkins 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Terminology

it gives a very vague but more wider meaning of the term build. Can anyone please explain the meaning of "build" it is trying to convey. I am a little confused as the literal meaning of the word "build" w.r.t s/w is, I suppose "to built an .exe or .apk or some file format that can be executed directly in a machine". Kindly help!

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry abt that, now I corrected !

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/) documentation link, a *build* is the *Result of a single execution of a Project*; most typically (but not necessarily) a build will generate an artifact, but the term *build* in the narrowest sense refers to a single execution (of a project). Your intuitive understanding is not totally wrong; however, the *thing that is build* is called an *artifact* in Jenkins terminology, while a *build* refers to the spercific run of the project which may have generated an artifact.

Comment: is there a reason to call it build if it isn't making an artifact . I am just curious, is it _de-facto_ or _de-jury_ . Thnks !

Comment: @Mitz I think this is more _de-jury_; Jenkins can also be used as an automization tool to _trigger stuff_ (like repeatedly calling Webservice methods or copy files), where no _artifact_ is generated as output of the job. The tern _build_ is a bit misleading then. Even more confusing - my coworkers and me are sometimes using the terms _build_ and _artifact_ interchangably to refer to the _artifact_.

Comment: Thanks @Codor for your time !